# windows store app(passing two fields through a command parameter) on the click of a button

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am working on a windows store app. I want to be able to pass two parameter on the click of a button to another page.
I am able to pass one conveniently like the line below

```
       CommandParameter="{Binding  CustomerServiceRepresentativeId}"
```

How can I pass an additional field like the one below making two fields passed to the destination page.

```
       Binding CustomerServiceRepresentativeName
```

I have had no luck passing the two.

```
                <GridView x:Name="GVCSRList" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="None" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}" Width="Auto" Margin="40,0,0,0">                           
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource CSRProfile}" Margin="0,0,10,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  CommandParameter="{Binding  CustomerServiceRepresentativeId}">
                        <StackPanel Width="290" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Tag="CSRListName"  Text="{Binding CustomerServiceRepresentativeName}" Style="{StaticResource CntMedTextBlockStyleBold}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,15"/> 
                        </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate> 
                </GridView>



                        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {

                                        var commandParameter = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
                                        if (commandParameter != null)
                                            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CSRProfile), commandParameter.ToString());
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        throw ex;
                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind to a new property that has both memebers:

E.g., right now you have:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public int CustomerServiceRepresentativeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceRepresentativeName { get; set; }
}
```

Put those in a separate class, and add a property of that type to your class. E.g.:

```
class IdNameCombo
{
    public int CustomerServiceRepresentativeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceRepresentativeName { get; set; }
}

class MyClass 
{
    public IdNameCombo IdName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you bind to the new property:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding IdName}"
```

To set or get the *id* or the *name*, you will need to type a little bit more:

```
MyClass myClass;
myClass.IdName.CustomerServiceRepresentativeId = 1;
myClass.IdName.CustomerServiceRepresentativeName = "Bob";
```

Comment: Thanks. Where will the last 3 lines of code reside Myclass.... Will this reside in this click event  [ ButtonBase_OnClick]

Comment: Sorry, fixing code. Is just an example of the changes you will need to do wherever you initialize the old properties.